# How to call relative path of batch file from python

Tags: python, path, relative-path

How do I call the relative path of batch file from python?

My python script 'Script.py' is in the directory "d:\2014\python\script.py"
from this file i would like to call a batch file "d:\2014\input\batch1.bat" but i want to use relative path with `popen()` function.

In Script.py

```
import os, sys
from subprocess import Popen
p = Popen("D:\\2014\\input\\batch1.bat", cwd=r"D:\\2014\\input")
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

the above code will work but the below code will not work

```
p = Popen("..\\input\\batch1.bat", cwd=r"..\\input")
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

gives file not found error

Answer (score 2):

Python will take the path from which you execute as the current directory. You can retrieve the current directory with os.getcwd().

Let's say I have a python script on my desktop to test this called pycwd.py:

```
import os
print os.getcwd()
```

Called from different places, it'll give different results:

```
C:\Users\me>python Desktop\pycwd.py
C:\Users\me
C:\Users\me\Desktop>python pycwd.py
C:\Users\me\Desktop
```

You'd want to use the solution SiHa suggested above:

```
path_to_directory_of_this_python_file = os.path.dirname(__file__)
path_to_your_batch_file = os.path.join(path_directory_of_this_python_file, '..', 'input', 'batch1.bat')
p = Popen(path_to_your_batch_file)
```

The cwd argument in Popen is the path from where you want to execute your batchfile (f.e. if the batchfile expects to be only called from a certain directory).
EDIT: so for your jarfile: set cwd in popen to the directory where your jar file resides. Can you give this as a relative path to either the python file or the batch file or is it an absolute path only?

Answer (score 1):

From the python [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html):

"If cwd is not None, the child’s current directory will be changed to cwd before it is executed. Note that this directory is not considered when searching the executable, so you can’t specify the program’s path relative to cwd."

A very similar question was posed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270951/python-how-to-refer-to-relative-paths-of-resources-when-working-with-code-repo), try:

```
[...]
fn = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "..\\input\\batch1.bat")
p = Popen(fn, cwd=r"D:\\2014\\input")
[...]
```

Comment: Thanks all for your comments, but one more thing i forget to mention.Am calling one xyz.jar file from the bat file. batch file is throwing error "unable to access jar file xyz.jar". how to make to run the jar file ?

Comment: I'd say that's a different question. If someone has answered your original question, (enabled you to run the batch file) mark it as answered and then ask another about running a java file from a batch file - that's not a Python problem.

Comment: Actually, I'd have to disagree. I think he can perfectly run the java file from a batch file. However, his error indicates that the cwd argument in Popen has to be set to the directory the batch files expects to be run from (so it can find the jar file). Alternatively, he could also edit his batch file to make it not depend on which directory the batch file is executed from.