# Python - [Errno 2] No such file or directory,

Tags: python

I am trying to make a minor modification to a python script made by my predecessor and I have bumped into a problem. I have studied programming, but coding is not my profession.

The python script processes SQL queries and writes them to an excel file, there is a folder where all the queries are kept in .txt format. The script creates a list of the queries found in the folder and goes through them one by one in a for cycle.

My problem is if I want to rename or add a query in the folder, I get a "[Errno 2] No such file or directory" error. The script uses relative path so I am puzzled why does it keep making errors for non-existing files.

```
queries_pathNIC = "./queriesNIC/"

def queriesDirer():
    global filelist
    l = 0
    filelist = []
    for file in os.listdir(queries_pathNIC):
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            l+=1
            filelist.append(file)
    return(l)
```

Where the problem arises in the main function:

```
for round in range(0,queriesDirer()):
    print ("\nQuery :",filelist[round])
    file_query = open(queries_pathNIC+filelist[round],'r'); # problem on this line
    file_query = str(file_query.read())
```

Contents of queriesNIC folder

- 00_1_Hardware_WelcomeNew.txt
- 00_2_Software_WelcomeNew.txt
- 00_3_Software_WelcomeNew_AUTORENEW.txt

The scripts runs without a problem, but if I change the first query name to
"00_1_Hardware_WelcomeNew_sth.txt" or anything different, I get the following error message:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './queriesNIC/00_1_Hardware_WelcomeNew.txt'
```

I have also tried adding new text files to the folder (example: "00_1_Hardware_Other.txt") and the script simply skips processing the ones I added altogether and only goes with the original files.

I am using Python 3.4.

Does anyone have any suggestions what might be the problem?

Thank you

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1270951/3001761

Comment: Which OS you are using?

Comment: How is this script run? Are there other parts? Because `filelist` is global, it might well be that it is modified somewhere else or even saved between runs to avoid re-processing already processed files.

Answer (score 1):

The following approach would be an improvement. The `glob` module can produce a list of files ending with `.txt` quite easily without needing to create a list.

```
import glob, os

queries_pathNIC = "./queriesNIC/"

def queriesDirer(directory):
    return glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, "*.txt"))

for file_name in queriesDirer(queries_pathNIC):
    print ("Query :", file_name)

    with open(file_name, 'r') as f_query:
        file_query = f_query.read()
```

From the sample you have given, it is not clear if you need further access to the `round` variable or the file list.