# How to resolve relative paths in python?

Tags: python, path

I have Directory structure like this

```
projectfolder/fold1/fold2/fold3/script.py
```

now I'm giving script.py a path as commandline argument of a file which is there in

```
fold1/fold_temp/myfile.txt
```

So basically I want to be able to give path in this way

```
../../fold_temp/myfile.txt 

>>python somepath/pythonfile.py -input ../../fold_temp/myfile.txt
```

Here problem is that I might be given full path or relative path so I should be able to decide and based on that I should be able to create absolute path.

I already have knowledge of functions related to path.

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918154/relative-paths-in-python)

[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270951/python-how-to-refer-to-relative-paths-of-resources-when-working-with-code-repo)

Reference questions are giving partial answer but I don't know how to build full path using the functions provided in them.

Comment: If the user passed in a correct path, why do you care whether it is absolute or relative?  Python certainly doesn't care, and your user probably doesn't care.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get an absolute file path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51520/how-to-get-an-absolute-file-path-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
path = raw_input()
if os.path.isabs(path):
    print "input path is absolute"
else:
    path = os.path.join(dir, path)
    print "absolute path is %s" % path
```

Use os.path.isabs to judge if input path is absolute or relative, if it is relative, then use os.path.join to convert it to absolute

Comment: This doesn't work as a solution as in dir path you will have  a path for script file where as according to question I don't want to give that as a path..

Comment: Similer solution is there in links provided in question... it is perfectly fine if your input file is in same directory or in some subdirectory having same parent

Comment: `os.path.join(dir, path)` is already equal to `path`, if `path` is absolute (tested on Pyhon 3.6).

Comment: I am facing another situation, this method works for me, thank you

Comment: Thanks @Hooting! I have learnt something here when I came here to have the same question. This plus the answers above made my code more robust. So I upvote the answer here!

Answer (score 96):

try  [os.path.abspath](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html), it should do what you want ;)

Basically it converts any given path to an absolute path you can work with, so you do not need to distinguish between relative and absolute paths, just normalize any of them with this function.

Example:

```python
from os.path import abspath
filename = abspath('../../fold_temp/myfile.txt')
print(filename)
```

It will output the absolute path to your file.

**EDIT:**

If you are using Python 3.4 or newer you may also use the [resolve()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.resolve) method of [pathlib.Path](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path). Be aware that this will return a Path object and not a string. If you need a string you can still use `str()` to convert it to a string.

Example:

```python
from pathlib import Path
filename = Path('../../fold_temp/myfile.txt').resolve()
print(filename)
```

Comment: provide a small example ... it is better than a link;
otherwise, a good answer and would be up-voted...

Answer (score 5):

**A practical example:**

`sys.argv[0]` gives you the name of the current script

`os.path.dirname()` gives you the relative directory name

thus, the next line, gives you the absolute working directory of the current executing file.

`cwd = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))`

Personally, I always use this instead of `os.getcwd()` since it gives me the script absolute path, independently of the directory from where the script was called.

Comment: Thank you, in 2022 <3 sys.argv[0] works great with `runpy.run_path()`

Answer (score 4):

For Python3, you can use pathlib's [resolve](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.resolve) functionality to resolve symlinks and `..` components.

You need to have a Path object however it is very simple to do convert between str and Path.

I recommend for anyone using Python3 to drop `os.path` and its messy long function names and stick to `pathlib` Path objects.

Comment: Some examples would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

In modern Python (3.4+), you can use `pathlib`, along with `__file__`, to resolve a relative path relative to the current script:

```
from pathlib import Path

p = Path(__file__).parent / "../../fold_temp/myfile.txt"
```

This is basically a one-liner. You don’t even need to `resolve()` the path, as you can directly work with the Path object like this:

```
with p.open() as f:
    ...
```

But yes, if you want to get the absolute path in string form, you can resolve it explicitly:

```
path = str(p.resolve())
```