# Error in using resolve() while naming output files

Tags: python

```
output_file_name = '{}__output1.xlsx'.format(str(in_file.resolve().stem))

output_file_path = str(Path(out_folder, output_file_name))
```

this code lines are giving the following error:

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'resolve'`

I am processing multiple files and trying to dynamically create a file name for the output files and the path for them. Need your help to sort out the error.

I am trying to save the file in the following way:

`df.style.applymap(color_code).\to_excel(output_file_path, engine="xlsxwriter")`

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32838760/how-to-resolve-relative-paths-in-python). I mean especially the comment by Salo.

Answer (score 0):

`resolve()` is a method on `Path` objects from Python's stdlib `pathlib` module. You should be able to fix it by converting the `str` to a `Path` object.

```
from pathlib import Path

output_file_name = '{}__output1.xlsx'.format(Path(in_file).resolve().stem)

output_file_path = str(Path(out_folder, output_file_name))
```

Comment: I did change the code as per your suggestion but it is still giving the same error.

Comment: I just edited my answer, notice the placement of the parentheses.