# Set a Subdirectory's File's Working Path Relative to A Parent Directory in Python

Tags: python, filepath

I have a project folder, `PythonProject`.
Within that Project folder I have a 2 subdirectories: `SubDirectory` & `DataSubDirectory`.

Within SubDirectory, I have a python file, TestFile.py which opens an external file, datafile.txt,  contained in DataSubDirectory.

Currently, I open this file as such; `open(..\\DataSubDirectory\\data.txt)`

Is there a method by which I can set any file paths within my `TestFile.py` to be relative to the parent project folder, so that if the file were moved to another Sub Directory, or placed in the parent directory even, I would not get a filepath error? The effect being that any file opened as such; `open(data\\data.txt)` would actually be opened as `open(PythonProject\\data\\data.txt)`, and not relative to whichever directory it is found?

Comment: See the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270951/python-how-to-refer-to-relative-paths-of-resources-when-working-with-code-repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running from Project folder, set a variable(PRJ_PATH) to os.getcwd() and use it for opening the file like open(os.path.join(PRJ_PATH, 'data', 'data.txt'))

If you are running from subdirectories, set a variable(PRJ_PATH) to os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '..') and then use it for opening the file like open(os.path.join(PRJ_PATH, 'data', 'data.txt'))

Comment: Thank you, this method worked fine. The following usage seems to address my concern: `projectpath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '..', '..')`

`file = open(os.path.join(projectpath, 'DataSubDirectory', 'data.txt'))` which successfully opens a file from a folder two directories above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PythonProject = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]))` to set the PythonProject Path