# How to open file in python when file is stored in directory where all .py file is stored and how to open file when it stored in different directory

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new at learning python and i don't know which default directory python use to open file.

I have read some of the similar question answer on stackoverflow but didn't helped me. I'm running python 3.6.2.

I have following code where 'test.txt' file is stored where all .py files stored but i'm getting

> FileNotFoundError: [Errono 2] No such file or directory: 'test.txt'

```
handle = open('test.txt')
for line in handle:
   print(line)
```

Comment: Thanks!!
suppose i have 100s of files in /home/jay/config directory and i have .py files in /home/jay directory. How can i open all files and search pattern ?

I tried following and got the error:
` import re`
 `import os`
`os.chdir(r'/home/juniper/configs/')`
`files = open('*')`
`for line in files :`
    `line = line.rstrip()`
   ` if re.search('Model' , line):`
        `print(line)`


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/juniper/test.py", line 4, in ?
    files = open('*')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '*'

Answer (score 0):

Same directory / relative Location: 
[How to refer to relative paths of resources when working with a code repository in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270951/how-to-refer-to-relative-paths-of-resources-when-working-with-a-code-repository)

Any directory: Just give the absolut path to open() function (e.g. in[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51520/how-to-get-an-absolute-file-path-in-python))

Answer (score 0):

Modules have a `__file__` attribute that points to the full path and filename the module is loaded from. You can use the `pathlib`-module to extract the path (cutting the `.py`-filename) and construct a new full pathname.

```
import mymodule

with open(pathlib.path(mymodule.__file__).parent / 'test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

That way wherever `mymodule` is loaded from `test.txt` will be opened from.

Comment: Not sure how i can create module and which directory i can put that module.

Answer (score 0):

i'm using linux if i want to open a file in a different location than my current working directory i would have done this

> myfile = open('/user/path/file')

example

> myfile = open('/root/Desktop/css/base.css', 'r')

Comment: I tried this ' handle = open('C:\Users\jay\Documents\Python Code\test') ' and gave me same error. I'm using windows.

Comment: suppose i have 100s of files in /home/jay/config directory and i have .py files in /home/jay directory. How can i open all files and search pattern ? I tried following and got the error: 

` import re` 
`import os` 
`os.chdir(r'/home/juniper/configs/')` 
`files = open('*')` 
`for line in files : `
`line = line.rstrip() `
`if re.search('Model' , line):` 
   `print(line)`

**Following is the error**

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/juniper/test.py", line 4, in ? files = open('') IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '' `