# Pyinstaller EXE's __file__ refers to a .py file

Tags: python, python-3.x, executable, pyinstaller

Situation: My Python script has a line of code that copies itself to another directory

```
shutil.copyfile(os.path.abspath(__file__), newPath)
```

Problem: The script is then compiled into an EXE and ran. The error given is as follows:

```
FileNotFoundError: No such file or Directory: "C:\Path\To\EXE\script.py"
```

As you can see, the EXE is looking for the `.py` version of itself (i.e. uncompiled version)

Question: Is there another Python command that can still let the executable find itself and not the `.py` version of itself?

Additional information: I was going to try to just replace `.py` with `.exe` and see if it works -- it would have if not for the program to fail if I change the name of the executable.

```
C:\ > script.exe
#Works as expected

C:\ > ren script.exe program.exe
C:\ > program.exe
FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory: "C:\script.py"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was stuck in this problem too. Finally I found the solution from the [official document](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html).

---

**Solution**:

Use `sys.argv[0]` or `sys.executable` to access the real path of the executed file.

---

**Explanation**:

This is because your executable is a `bundle` environment. In this environment, all the `__file__` constants are relative paths relative to a virtual directory (actually the directory where the initial entrance file lies in).

As instructed by the document, you can access the absolute by using `sys.argv[0]` or `sys.executable`, as they are pointing to the actually executed command. So in a `bundle` environment, you call `script.exe`, and `sys.executable` will be `script.exe`. While in a running live environment, you call `python script.path`, and `sys.executable` will be `python.exe`.

Comment: I found it out recently too, but didn't update the answer. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I found that `sys.executable` works only on .exe files but `sys.argv[0]` works when I run the script like this `python script.py` and when I build the script to exe and run it using cmd. This is how I reference things now: `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])), 'Resources')`

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
from os.path import abspath, splitext
fromfile_without_ext, ext = splitext(abspath(__file__))
shutil.copyfile(fromfile_without_ext + '.exe', newPath)
```

(Did not test it, but should work...)

Comment: I'll try it when I get to it. Thanks

Comment: That's not the correct way. Because the `__file__` const will always be a relative path to the entrance script (e.g. `script.py`) wherever and however you call the executable. The correct way is to use `sys.argv[0]` or `sys.executable`.