# Moving files in Python doesn't work once made executable using pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, glob, shutil

I have a script in Python that works fine, it creates about 1000 files once the script is ran.

So I implemented some code to move the files to a new folder once the script is ran.

```
import glob, os, shutil

source_dir = 'C:/Users/george/Desktop/my aemo app/a'
dst = 'C:/Users/george/Desktop/my aemo app/b'
files = glob.iglob(os.path.join(source_dir, "*.csv"))
for file in files:
    if os.path.isfile(file):
        shutil.copy2(file, dst)
```

This works fine when I run it in idle, however once made executable and I send the program to someone else, it doesn't move the files for them?

Comment: Does the other person have a `C:/Users/george` directory on their system?

Comment: No they do not.

Comment: Is there a way so it doesn't matter?

Comment: If they do not, then the copying won't work. You need to determine the source and destination directory names "on the fly" instead of hardcoding them into the script's code.

Comment: Right, I was thinking it wouldn't work. How do I go about that then? Thanks btw

Comment: One possibility would be to determine the current user's username. There are ways of doing that on Windows (and most other OSs). Another would be to just ask the user.

Comment: Is there a way to do that automatically

Comment: It's not automatically. You would probably need to call at least one function. It may also not a great idea hardcoding those sub-directory names in as well—but I have no idea what you're doing overall so can't suggest anything as far as they are concerned.

Comment: So the program does all this stuff and ends up with about 1000csv files. So when you run the program you end up with like a thousand files wherever you ran the program from. So my goal is to move these thousand files into a new folder so that its not so messy

Comment: Is that kind of thing possible?

Comment: It's possible to move them, but you may need to ask the user where they want them to be put. As far as the current user goes, check-out the question [Is there a portable way to get the current username in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842059/is-there-a-portable-way-to-get-the-current-username-in-python)—and not just the first answer.

Comment: Just wherever the program is, make a folder in the same directory

Comment: `os.getcwd()` returns the current working directory. The script itself has a predefined variable named `__file__` with its filename in it—although using pyinstaller may break that. No more questions, please.

Comment: A workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50959340/pyinstaller-exes-file-refers-to-a-py-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine the problem with sending to another user is that their username probably isn't "george" and therefore their file structure is different than what your program is looking for. I would try using environment variables or relative pathways to move files around on a program that is to be distributed.
os documentation:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#process-parameters

relative pathways would be something like `../../file/deepFile/whatYoureLookingFor` if you want to go up 2 directories from where you run the program and then dive down another path into `file`

Comment: You could also have the user specify the path at runtime via GUI creation, or argument parsing. Argument parsing documentation is at https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html. and GUI creation is typically done with tkinter module for python, a good tutorial is at: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/

Comment: Is there a way so that it doesn't matter where the program is?

Comment: My goal is:
If i send someone the program and they open it in their downloads, it runs and makes a new folder in their downloads and puts all their files there.
Or if I send If i send someone the program and they open it somewhere else, e.g. their desktop it runs and makes a new folder in their desktop and puts all their files there.

Comment: Is that kind of thing possible?

Comment: Yes, you can use environment variables. Try the following in a console: 
>import os
>os.environ

Comment: in that case use relative pathways. Don't specify a full path from C:\\...... use something like 'my aemo app/a' instead

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187149/discussion-between-newtor-and-reedinationer).

Comment: i mean an interactive shell

Comment: Oh I found the mistake in the code I sent you! where i put 
`if __name__ == 'main'` it should be:
`if __name__ == "__main__"`

Comment: That created the folders but it doesn’t move them?

Comment: have you tried troubleshooting with print statements? Something like `for file in files: print(file.__next__())`?