# How can I get the script / exe directory with pathlib in python?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, windows-task-scheduler, pathlib

I made a script in Python 3.9.2 that uses pathlib `(pathlib.Path.cwd())` to get current script's folder
(I then made an .exe file using PyInstaller)

If i start the script/exe manually no worries, but if I use windows scheduler or i start the script /.exe without beeing in the current folder, `pathlib.Path.cwd()` (correctly) gets the current folder where I am, not the script's folder

e.g.
in windows terminal

```
cd [...]\folderWithMyScript
py myScript.py
```

works good but if I'm in my home directory `C:\Users\myName` and I start the script from there

```
py [pathToTheScript]
```

It wont' work (since he can't find some other folder which are below the script folder, the whole script uses a lot  `.joinpath('something')`

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried some of the suggestion in the docs? https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html

Comment: @Ralf No, but now i'll look into it, thank you  
Although the problem is in the python script, a .exe made with pyinstaller and started with windows scheduler is just my final objective, but as i said the problem persist even if i launch the script.py straight up with python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you properly determine the current script directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718657/how-do-you-properly-determine-the-current-script-directory)

Comment: @AndrewMarshall this is like the answer i got in this thread, I will try it but i honestly wanted to use only pathlib and ignore the `os` lib

Comment: pathlib uses os anyway, so importing that shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 1):

[VersBersch's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66815405/how-can-i-get-the-script-exe-directory-with-pathlib-in-python/67375765?noredirect=1#comment118168997_66850131) answer should be the correct answer.

```
Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent[]
```

Comment: Instead of linking to their profile, can you link to the question/answer of what you mean?

Comment: Just changed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`pathlib.Path.cwd()` will not give you your script's folder, it is to get the current work directory. A.k.a where you run the command to run the script. The correct way to get your script's folder is: `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))`

see [How can I find script's directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934806/how-can-i-find-scripts-directory)

Comment: I've seen those thread. I will try this but i honestly wanted to use only pathlib and ignore the `os` lib

Comment: pathlib uses os anyway, so importing that shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 0):

So, in the end i gave up and used `os` lib

I did somethin like this (so i could still use the pathlib in the whole script)

```
trueDir = pathlib.Path(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
```

Thank you for all your kind answers !

Comment: with `pathlib` it's just `pathlib.Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent`

Answer (score 0):

Something important I just found out is, that you might run into troubles using `__file__` if you're going to convert youre program into an executable file. Instead you should use `sys.executable`. Took me a while to find out...
[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50959340/pyinstaller-exes-file-refers-to-a-py-file)

Answer (score 0):

```
file_path = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
```

for get the path directory of .exe