# Python doesn't recognize jpg image file/directory

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I can't get this image to be displayed in a tkinter gui because it doesn't recognize the image file or directory, here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = tk.Tk()

path = "krebs.jpg"
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
img.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

and here is the picture in question: [Krebs security pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhVMh.jpg)

Comment: Are you sure that "krebs.jpg" is in the current working directory? Please be aware that the current working directory and the directory where your script is located might differ.

Comment: That image isn't a jpg, it's a png.

Comment: Original picture link was a png instead of a jpg, sorry about that, fixed now.

Comment: Problem was just a typo as per comment of requester, so question can be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I believe there is a simpler solution and one that is better overall. Python can use `.` to tell the code that the file you are looking for is in your same directory as your python code. This way you do not need to select a file manually or use a complete file path name.

2nd I noticed you are trying to `pack()` an image into the window however you cannot do this. Instead add it to a label or canvas. Just make sure your image file is in the same folder as your .py file.

Try this.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = tk.Tk()

path = "./krebs.jpg"
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
lbl = tk.Label(root, image=img)
lbl.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I used a simple small red square image I use for testing but here is the results:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I bet your current working directory isn't what you think it is. Try:

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

Make sure that directory (printed by `os.getcwd()`) has your image in it (i.e. go to that folder and check to see if your image is there). If not, specify the absolute path to your image:

```
path = C:/Users/<user_name>/... .../krebs.jpg
```

or whatever the full path to the image is on your OS.

Alternatively, you could move the image to the folder indicated by `os.getcwd()`.

Sometimes I make a typo when defining paths in python, because very simple IDEs (like IDLE) don't have in-line auto-complete. Here's a trick I use all the time to make sure my absolute path doesn't have a typo:

```
import tkinter.filedialog as fd
path = fd.askopenfilename()
```

It will open a familiar file opening dialog. Use the file dialog window to find your file, then click "Open", and you'll have the full path saved to variable "path".

Comment: if your image is in the same directory as your source code, you could do something like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1270970/1358308

Comment: That worked in order to select the picture I needed. However, after copying the picture to the directory it showed, it still won't automatically display the picture without manually selecting it

Comment: I wouldn't incorporate the fd.askopenfilename() into your program unless you want the filedialog to run every time. Do that in the python shell, and then copy/paste that path into your .py file.

Comment: Edit: describing the full path to the file under path worked, thanks! And by manually selecting I meant when "askopenfilename()" is ran, it directs me to the documents page of my pc where I was able to manually click the picture and use it. Apologies for the lack of clarity, I'm still pretty new to programming :)

Comment: How is it that I solved the problem, but my answer wasn’t the accepted one?