# Using crontab but python3 running path is root diretory

Tags: python, cron

Here is my python code: `/root/project/test.py`

```
file = open('./test.txt', 'a')
file.write('Hello World\n')
file.close()
```

when I use crontab

```
* * * * * python3 /root/project/test.py
```

to run the python demo

I want the `test.txt` to be created and writed in the /`root/project/`
but actually it is created and writed in the /root/

I am so sad.
How can I do it without change the python code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1270970/1390548 see if this helps

Comment: Somehow the current directory must be /root/ when this cron job is executed. Try to find out why, and fix it. As an alternate, even "* * * * * cd /root/project/; python3 test.py" should work

Comment: thank you !  I am so happy that so many people helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run cron record for particular user it use home directory of this user. You can try two different approaches:

1. do `cd` in the `cron` record: `* * * * * cd /root/project; python3
   test.py`
2. set path (absolute or relative in your code): `file =
   open('project/test.txt', 'a')` or `file =
   open('/root/project/test.txt', 'a')`

Comment: @lch-howger iff you are happy with my answer feel free to upvore and/or accept the answer